# Send a redirect after finishing an asynchronous process

Tags: java, servlets, redirect

An external process is creating a file, and I'd like to send a redirect after the file has been created. I'm running into a problem where the redirect is happening before the file has finished being written to.

I thought putting the thread to sleep might help, but it seems that the thread never goes to sleep (I can put sleep(10000000) and I'm still redirected almost immediately), and the sendRedirect always occurs as soon as the file is created.

```
while (!myFile.exists())
{
 Thread.sleep(100);
}

Thread.sleep(1000); // let the file finish being written to.

response.sendRedirect("myPath");
```

Comment: show the code how you using to write in a file i.e which method and class

Comment: Why are you using a thread to begin with? If you want asynchronous, use Ajax to send the request, then have it return back to you a link to the file when it completes.  No need to create your own thread on the server-side.